# Html With Image Background CSS

Tags: html, css

Good morning everyone.

I have this HTML CODE who put an image on my background page.

**1/ How do I add on this code line to make sure the image is not going to be repeated where we are going to go down on the page ?

2/Also.... How do I add on this code line the size of the image

        "width": 1400,
        "height": 1050** ?

I tried to look everywhere but could not find answers.

Thank you for your help :)

```html
<body class="boxed_layout" style="background-image: url('images/background-1.jpg');">
```

Answer (score 1):

I will answer you point by point:

1. You can do that using this `style` -> `style="background-image: url('images/background-1.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;"`
2. Setting the `width` and `height` in this way mean that the image doesn't fit all screen. If you want to do this, remove `background-size` attribute and add into style this: `width: 1400px; height: 1050px`

Comment: Thank you so so so so much for your help. It seems so easy for everybody but it's really hard for me. It does work, this work very well and thank you for your details  but as soon as I move the page down, the image changed and I dont know why, but it is a HUGE ZOOMING and the image is not clear anymore

Comment: If you are following the second point it's normal that you see your image zoomed because you're setting statically width and height values. As I've already said, if you want to see your image in right dimensions you should try to follow only the first point.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body class="boxed_layout" style="background-image: url('images/background-1.jpg') no-repeat; width: 1400; height: 1050">
</ body>
```

Because your using a background image,  I don't believe your able to set the image dimensions directly.  Setting the height and width as indicated will set the body's height and width. Otherwise, you will need to  create a child element of the body and place the background image on the child element with the corresponding dimensions you want set.